# Trying to select a child element in the same div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, parent-child

I am having issues using the ~ to select a child element inside of the same div.

```
HTML Example

<div class="about one"></div>

CSS Example

.about ~ .one {
   background-color: #0068bf;
}
```

Simply saying, I want to select the one inside the about div and change properties (like the background color).

Here's my code:

```
HTML Snippet:

        <div class="about-wrapper">
            <div class="about one">
                <div class="title">
                    About Title
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    A basic description
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
CSS Snippet:

.about-wrapper {
    display: grid;  
    grid-template-areas: 
        "About  Empty"
        "Join   Empty";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    margin: 12vh;
}

.about {
    background-color: #2b2b2b64;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 2vw;
}

.about ~ .one { /* This is the only thing that wont work */
    background-color: #0068bf;
    grid-column-start: 1fr;
    grid-column-end: 3fr;
}

.about .title {
    font-family: 'Rubik 80s Fade', cursive;
    font-size: 2.75vw;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.about .desc {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 2vw;
    letter-spacing: -0.1vw;
    color: #ffffffe8;
}
```

I've used this before in a previous site and it worked just fine but it doesn't seem to be working here. The code is the same as the other code pretty much. I've been at this awhile so if anyone has an answer please help. (I also searched everywhere and couldn't find anything helpful).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.about-wrapper {
    display: grid;  
    grid-template-areas: 
        "About  Empty"
        "Join   Empty";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    margin: 12vh;
}

.about {
    background-color: #2b2b2b64;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 2vw;
}

.about ~ .one { /* This is the only thing that wont work */
    background-color: red;
    grid-column-start: 1fr;
    grid-column-end: 3fr;
}

.about .title {
    font-family: 'Rubik 80s Fade', cursive;
    font-size: 2.75vw;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.about .desc {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 2vw;
    letter-spacing: -0.1vw;
    color: #ffffffe8;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-wrapper">
            <div class="about one">
                <div class="title">
                    About Title
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    A basic description
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="one">
            ~ is a selector for siblings. So it effects THIS div (the sibling of about one) 
            <div/>
        </div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The tilde combinator (`~`) targets siblings only.

Your CSS rule...

```
.about ~ .one
```

is saying:

*Select all elements with a class `one` that are preceded by a sibling element with a class `about`.*

Therefore, your title:

**Trying to select a child element using ~**

... is self-explanatory. You don't select child elements with this tool.

To select child elements, use the descendant ( ) or child (`>`) combinators.

More details here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors

Comment: This doesn't work either.